# Invert probabilities (lowest value having highest probability in a set)

Tags: probability

I have a set of values $(v_1,v_2,..,v_n)$ positive integers. I want to assign probabilities depending on the value, with the lowest having the highest probability. The sum of probabilities should be $1$ for the whole set.

I can do it the other way around if I find $t = \sum v_i$ then $p(v_i) = \frac{v_i}{t}$ but the lowest value has the least probability.

Comment: Obviously it can be done in many ways and it is not clear to me what's your criteria to decide what is the "good" solution that would work for you. Why not try just $p(v_i)=\frac{v_{n+1-i}}{t}$ (which is really the same as your formula above just re-assigning the probabilities in the opposite order)?

Comment: @StinkingBishop you are right I didn't specify. I am actually trying to do this with code and when calculating for $v_i$ I can only use it and the total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A natural assignement is
$$p(v_i)=\frac{1/v_i}{\sum_i1/v_i}$$
Since all $v_i$ are positive, we can safely reciprocate them, which turns high values into low values and vice versa. Then we apply the "other way round" assignment.

This has the advantage that same values have same probabilities.